Characterizing Singular Borel Measures through Continuous Functions
This is from a 2008 Texas qualifier, namely question 10 here:

Write $\mu$ for the Lebesgue measure on the Borel subsets of the unit interval $[0,1]$. Recall that a Borel probability measure $\nu$ on $[0,1]$ is singular with respect to $\mu$ (in symbols, $\nu \perp \mu$) if there is a Borel set $D \subseteq [0,1]$ such that $\nu(D) = 1$ and $\mu(D) = 0$. Let $\nu$ be a Borel probability measure on $[0,1]$. Show that $\nu \perp \mu$ if and only if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a continuous function $f : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ such that $\nu(f) > 1 - \varepsilon$ and $\mu(f) < \varepsilon$.

I feel like I am cheating a little bit with partitions of unity on the forward direction. Maybe there is a solution which has a more measure theoretic flavor? Also, it took me an incredible amount of time to think of the Lebesgue decomposition in the other direction, I was trying to use Borel Cantelli, but it didn't work. Is there a nice trick for this problem? Anyways, my solution is given below. Any thoughts and alternative solutions are welcome.

$(\Rightarrow )$ For the forward direction I decided to use partitions of unity. Namely, because the Lebesgue measure is taken as infimum of open sets we may find an open set $U$ such that $D\subseteq U$ and $\mu(U\setminus D)<\varepsilon$.  Let me take a partition of unity $\rho_i$ subbordinate to the open set $U$. It is clear that by the Monotone Convergence Theorem:
$$\lim_n\int \sum_{i=1}^n \rho_i d\nu=\int \sum \rho_i d\nu=\int_D 1d\nu=1$$
We choose $n$ so large that for $f=\sum_{i=1}^n\rho_i$:
$$\int f d\mu>1-\varepsilon$$
Now, it is also clear that due to partition of unity properties that $\sum_{i=1}^n \rho_i\leq 1$ and also that it is zero on $U^C$. Hence:
$$\int f d\mu\leq \int_U 1d\mu=\int_D1d\mu+\int_{U\setminus D}d\mu=\varepsilon$$
$(\Leftarrow)$ Let us consider the Lebesgue decomposition for $\nu$ with respect to $\mu$ given by $\nu=\nu_a+\nu_s$.
Our quest is showing $\nu_a([0,1])=0$ and hence, $\nu=\nu_s\perp \mu$. To prove this, let us take $f_n$ with $\int f_n d\nu\geq 1-1/n^2$ and $\int f_n d\mu \leq 1/n^2$. It is clear that:
$$\frac{1}{2}\mu(f_n>1/2)\leq\int f_n d\mu\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$$
And so, because $\nu_a<<\mu$, there is $n$ so large that:
$$\nu_a(f_n>1/2)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$
Reciprocally, notice that:
$$\frac{1}{2}\nu(f_n\leq 1/2)+\nu(f_n> 1/2)\geq \int f_n d\nu \geq 1-\frac{1}{n^2}$$
$$ \frac{1-\nu(f_n\leq 1/2)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\nu(f_n>1/2)\geq \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n^2}$$
$$\therefore \nu_a(f_n\leq 1/2) \leq\nu(f_n\leq1/2)<\frac{2}{n^2}$$
Combining both bounds we are done as it teaches that for $n$ large enough:
$$\nu_a([0,1])=\nu_a(f_n>1/2)+\nu_a(f_n\leq 1/2)\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{2}{n^2}<\varepsilon$$
Because $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, we are done, $\nu=\nu_s\perp \mu$.
